# How to change the size of desktop/window fonts in Puppy Linux 4.1?

Tags: linux, puppylinux

How to change the size of desktop/window fonts in Puppy Linux 4.1?

Comment: Oh man..you should just bump it in some way..bounty for this? :) .. I'll tell you tomorrow hopefully. (But ..people will answer it sooner for the bounty I guess.)

Answer (score 2):

Not using Puppy, I wonder if this article has the answer :

[Puppy 5 - Font size too small](http://www.murga-linux.com/puppy/viewtopic.php?t=56203&sid=d59704ef0ca58b29068bd475a2345dcc)

> menu / desktop / desktop settings /
>   set global font size, change font size, restart X

Answer (score 1):

Should just be: Menu->Desktop->Set global font size

Comment: Better to read the other answers before answering ...

Answer (score 0):

Clarifying exactly which fonts do get changed is worthwhile in and of itself.

The `setglobalfontsize` command does not appear to change the size of fonts in the console window, even after restarting X. Instead, the `setfont` command appears to be the correct solution, but I am still working my way through finding out how to use it. However, I did notice that using `setglobalfontsize` did alter the size of the font used on the desktop and the font used after the puppy desktop closed and before it was reopened by X.

Because the use of fonts have been around for a VERY long time, and also because it can be somewhat demanding, the entire technology has become very baroque.

In Slacko 5.5, which I am using, some of the fonts appear to be located in /lib/consolefonts, as suggested by some posts. But the main trove of fonts are located under /usr/share/fonts/default, in TTF and Type1, both are directories. The man page for `setfont` appears to be very helpful. The aim is to find the correct `setfont` command to insert into either .bashrc (for an individual effect by user) or into /etc/profile (for a global effect).

It will take a little further messing around, but I believe I am on the right path.